# What lightweight household items could be used as tent stakes?

Tags: camping

I've gotta go on a backpacking trip, and I need something lightweight to attach rainfly to fairly soft ground. Doesn't even have to be super-ultra-rigid, just light.

Normally I'd just order something online, but that'd take a week or so to arrive here (and i don't have the time for that).

Answer (score 3):

Will there be trees? If yes, you could use loose wood from the ground as tent pegs. Then you could take some rope/washing line and attach it to a branch to lift up the centre of the tent, rather than using a stake inside (that would be a lot easier to carry than any stakes).

Without trees you could try pegging with cutlery. Maybe you could use a broomstick or some bamboo item to use as a stake. This is somewhat difficult to answer without knowing what you've got in your home, but I trust you get the idea. Bring some extra line anyway.

Don't forget to take a knife to cut things to the right lengh. Preferably one with a saw attachment.

Comment: Not to be too picky; but, how do trees and loose wood constitute household items? Where do you live, in the woods?

Comment: @Stan ... as a matter of fact I do. Or close enough anyway. More to the point while on a camping trip even a city dweller will take temporary residence wherever the tent is pitched, which may well be in the woods too and I would count things potentially lying around your camping site as close enough fitting the definition of household items to fit this site.

Comment: Came back. Lessons learned - forest/camping site ground is not always necessarily soft - at least not soft enough as loose wood is often too brittle for it - or too thick - so a sharp knife is a necessity for using loose wood as a stake. I managed without, but there were no strong winds.

Comment: I feel that some of the *disposable* plastic forks or knifes or spoons (at least their handles are fairly sharp and durable) could work well, but i have to test this.

Answer (score 0):

Look around. You have all kinds of common household items that can be used: wood spoon, plastic spatula, old silverware, or steak knives. Pencils, pens, rulers, coat hangers, shoe horns, broken drum sticks, etc.